# SOLVED: su with new user automatically fails without asking for a password

Tags: password, openstack, user-management, adduser

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.5. I've created a user called test_user and when I try the command

```
su test_user
```

I get the output

```
user@user:~$ su test_user
su: Authentication failure
user@user:~$
```

Without asking for any password. I cannot SSH into the machine as that user as well.

EDIT: I found the problem.

I'm pretty sure it was PAM not allowing users to login

On my system there is a file `/etc/groups.allow`

I appended the username of the user I just created to the end of this file and now I can su to the user and use ssh with that user.

Comment: How did you "create" `test_user`? What were the results? Can you login as `test_user`?

Comment: I just did it with

`sudo adduser test_user`

and followed the regular prompts

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: Then why did you remove the solution?

Comment: Please put the solution as an answer below. To mark the question as solved, please use the checkmark next to the answer after the appropriate time has passed.